# How do I truncate milliseconds off "Ticks" without converting to datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two times in `Ticks` like so:

```
//2016-01-22​T17:34:52.648Z
var tick1 = 635890808926480754;

//2016-01-22​T17:34:52.000Z
var tick2 = 635890808920000000;
```

Now as you can see comparing these two numbers `tick1 == tick2 returns false`

although the dates are the same (apart from milliseconds).

I would like to truncate the milliseconds off these numbers without converting it to a datetime (because this would reduce efficiency)

I have looked at [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) which says:

> Rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of fractional digits.

and also [Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70(v=vs.110).aspx) neither of which I think do what I need.

Looking at [Datetime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

Therefore I need to round the number down to the nearest ten million.

Is this possible?

Comment: divide it by 10000000f and use Math.Ceil on the result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use integer division:

```
if (tick1 / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond == tick2 / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
```

This works because if you divide a `long`/`int` by a `long`/`int` the result is also a `long`/`int` therefore truncating the decimal portion.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting up voted. If `tick1 == tick2 returns false` then `tick1 / 10000000 == tick2 / 10000000` would also return false unless you truncate after the division. Thats just algebra? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user1 Because he is truncating. If you devide a `long` or `int` by a `long` or `int` the result is also a `long` or `int` truncating the decimal portion.

Comment: @scottChamberlain you are correct. Coming from a mathematical background, I hate numbers in computer science

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
if(Math.Abs(tick1 - tick2) < TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
```

Which avoid doing  divisions.

You may adjust the precision you need with any of the following:

- `TimeSpan.TicksPerDay`
- `TimeSpan.TicksPerHour`
- `TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute`
- `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`
- `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond`

Comment: avoiding divisions for the win

Answer (score -1):

Divide it by 1000 like this:

```
Long Seconds = 635890808926480754/1000

//Seconds = 635890808926480
```

Comment: Downvoter may comment also. It will help me understand my mistake.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I wasn't the downvoter. I would never downvote without knowing for sure that an answer is incorrect

Comment: Dividing by 1000 is not enough.  As per the other answer (and the quote in the question - _"10 million ticks in a second"_), you need to do it by 10,000,000.